# Illegal String Offset PHP with Foreach statement

Tags: php, sql, foreach

I'm having a little problem with the code. The code is meant to display check if they said if they're attending or not. If so, displays that. If not, displays table with date and asking to insert they're attendance.

```
$rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($defaulttable)

foreach($rows as $row){

    $is_found = false;
    foreach($rows2 as $row2){

        if($row2['id'] == $row['date_id']){
            $is_found = true;
            echo 'Display attendance data'.'<br />'; //echo to see if it has matched an id
            //Display attendance table
        }
    }


    if($is_found == false){
        echo 'Display default'.'<br />'; // echo to see if its default
        //Display default
    }
}
```

When this is ran, there is a **Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'** and **Warning: Illegal string offset 'date_id'**

Anybody know why this is?

Comment: What's in `$row` and `$row2`? You can check with something like `var_dump($row);`

Comment: `$rows` and `$rows2` are just one row from the table, not all the rows.

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_all()` to fetch all rows.

Comment: You should use a `JOIN` to find the matching rows in the database, rather than looping in PHP.

Comment: I would print_r both arrays and see what they contain for each iteration of your loop.
You also could use in_array to check if that id exists in the other array.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Can you show us your sql query, as well? It's possible that you have an sql query that isn't returning what you want it to.

Comment: @E2017 It's clear what's wrong. He's looping through the columns, but treating them as rows.

Comment: Try to replace `$row2['id'] == $row['date_id']` with `$row2->id == $row->date_id` because the result is in assoc format not in simple indexed array format.

Comment: $defaulttable = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM jan');
   

   $sql = 'Select * FROM attendance_jan WHERE callsign = "'.$callsign.'"';